# How to make the number of swaps zero in Quicksort algorithm for an already sorted array?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Is there any way to achieve the number of swaps zero for an already sorted ascending array list.

```
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
         // If current element is smaller than or
         // equal to pivot
         if (arr[j] <= pivot)
          {
           printf("inside if");
           i++;    // increment index of smaller element
           swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
           no_of_comparisons++;
          }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}
```

Comment: `if (std::is_sorted(arr, arr + size)) { return;}` ? (in quicksort, not in partition).

Comment: Is the idea to save half a nanosecond by not swapping two `int`s? Because the result will be the same for objects without identity. Otherwise you have [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) when preserving the order is important.

Comment: Why are you swapping equal items? If you fix that, then there's no way an already-sorted array can do any swaps. That doesn't help the running time any, of course, because the problem is recursion depth.

Comment: I am not swapping any equal items, which line are you referring to?

I also tried doing quicksort using middle element as pivot and the no of swaps has now reduced from 11 to 2, but it is still not 0

Code for middle element as pivot--> https://pastebin.com/yJ9xJYaw

Answer (score 0):

If you use the middle element rather than the last element in the list (and rearrange the algorithm slightly), you can avoid swapping.

For optimum qsort, you are better off using the median of the first, last, and middle element (known as "median of three").

If you are concerned about the performance sorting attacker generated data (qsort has average O(n log n) performance, but worst-case O(n²)), use a *random* pivot.

Note:  I can see the question is about `partition` and not `qsort`, but it's quite likely to be in the context of `qsort`.

Comment: Although the number of swaps has reduced when using the middle element as pivot from 11 to 2, but it is still not showing 0 swaps for ascending sorted list

New code for middle element as pivot: https://pastebin.com/LJXXAus7

Comment: That's what I meant by "and rearrange the algorithm slightly" - you want to avoid that call to swap on line 25, and the call to swap which makes it necessary.  'i' is the index at the bottom of the unpartitioned range, j is the index at the top of the unpartitioned range. 
 While list[i] is less-equal pivot, incremented i;  similarly for j.  Then swap list[i], list[j], and advance both i and j.  Loop until i greater-equal j

Comment: I accidentally pasted the wrong link, this is the correct link

https://pastebin.com/yJ9xJYaw

This updated code calls the swap function only once as compared to the earlier code when using last element as pivot. The problem is that the number of swaps is still not zero but 2